# Does it make a difference where Git is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I was reading a blog post about installing git, and it says it will be installed in `/usr/bin/git`

When I check my version using `$ which git`, terminal shows `/usr/local/bin/git`. Same result when I checked for Ruby. Does it make different where Git, Ruby or Rails are installed? Can I change that if it's possible?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter where the commands are as long as your `PATH` is set up properly.

Comment: You can install anything anywhere(given proper permissions), so where a program ends up depends on how you installed it.  Did you install all those programs the same way the blogger did?  Why do you want to change where your programs are installed?

Comment: For what's it worth: `$ which git => /usr/local/git/bin/git`  I had no idea it was installed in that directory, and I install everything by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, it should not matter. But, usually, `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` in the `PATH` environment variable. So, in future, if another version of the same software, lets say git,  is installed into `/usr/local/bin`, that will take precedence over the one installed in `/usr/bin`. You can of course manipulate your `PATH` environment variable to suite your needs.

run this command to see if multiple versions of git have been installed

`which -a git`

Comment: the result of 'which -a git' is
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
/usr/local/git/bin/git

When I i did "which git" I got;
/usr/local/bin/git

what does it mean? why I have 3? which one I'm using all the time? do u think Git might not work properly?

Comment: `which git` returns the first occurrence of the executable when searching in the order of your `PATH` variable. `which -a git` shows all occurrences. If you are seeing more than one instance of `git`, it could mean you have multiple versions installed. It could also mean you have symlinked an executable into another folder. You can run the command `file -h /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git /usr/local/git/bin/git` to check if a given file is a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter as long as all of them are accessible in your `PATH` for commands.

Is your concern about where the actual repositories will be located - the place where GIT repositories are located is not necessarily the same place where GIT itself is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could change it. It might not be worth it.

It will probably be easier just to leave it and remember.

This is sorta like windows install path. Default will be "Program Files" but it often can be changed.

Note that different versions of Windows have differently named program files. This can be an example of such differences also.

Finally it could be that your ruby installed GIT, and that is the path that Ruby chose.

As long as `/usr/local/bin/git` is in your PATH you should not notice any differences.

Comment: Err, Ruby doesn't install Git.

Comment: I was speculating. Could be a package of ruby that sets of git somehow. My point is that they may be linked thats all.